# Woocommerce required checkbox before adding the product to the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a checkbox that needs to be clicked before a product can be added to the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_privacy_policy', 9 );
```

```
    function add_privacy_policy() {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
    'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
    'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
    'required'      => true,
    'label'         => 'I\'ve read and accept the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>',
    )); 

    }
```

This is what I have so far. I now need to create an action that fires after I clicked the add to cart button but before the product is actually placed into the cart. If the box is not ticked I want to make it so that it outputs an error and the product is not added to the cart.

As I don't really know woocommerce I wanted to know whether there's such an action and if not, how to create the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the follows code snippet -

```
function add_privacy_policy_validation( $passed ) { 
    if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['privacy_policy'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please accept privacy policy', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_privacy_policy_validation', 99 );
```